# extract data from XML depending of contents of specific tag

Tags: xml, bash

I have a xml-file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:policies xmlns:ns1="http://www.companyname.nl/exchange/policyimport" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <policy>
        <serialnumber>159</serialnumber>
        <relationnumber>159</relationnumber>
        <policynumber>2013000001</policynumber>
        <soort>2002</soort>
        <policyStatus>1</policyStatus>
        <startdate>2001-03-16</startdate>
        <enddate>2016-03-16</enddate>
        <label1>0</label1>
        <label2>100</label2>
        <btw>true</btw>
    </policy>
    <policy>
        <serialnumber>159</serialnumber>
        <relationnumber>159</relationnumber>
        <policynumber>2013000002</policynumber>
        <soort>2003</soort>
        <policyStatus>1</policyStatus>
        <startdate>2001-03-16</startdate>
        <enddate>2016-03-16</enddate>
        <label1>0</label1>
        <label2>100</label2>
        <btw>false</btw>
    </policy>
</ns1:policies>
```

I would like to extract data from a tag using a bash script, but depending on the contents of another tag. 
So for instance:
If the content of `<btw>` is true, then get the content of `<policynumber>` in that same block (in this case 2013000001).

If the content of `<soort>` is 2003 then get the content of `<policynumber>`in that same block(in this case 2013000002).

Is that possible in a bash script? I tried to figure it out using xmlstarlet, but I'm a newbie and couldn't get it done.
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `xmllint` with its **xpath builtin**. check if it is available in your current xmllint binary. otherwise you need to recompile xmllint.

`xmllint --help | grep "\-\-xpath"`

if it is available you can use:

`xmllint --xpath "//policy/btw[text()='true']/../policynumber" xmllint-xpath.file`

the command steps down all policies `//policy` checking the text value of btw  `btw[text()='true']` and if that is true it gathers btw's siblings by name moving upwards `..` first.

Answer (score 0):

This **xmlstarlet** command will return all `<policynumber>` values, separated by spaces, that are within `<policy>`s with `<btw>` values equal to 'true':

```
xml sel -t -m "//policy/btw[. = 'true']/../policynumber" -v "." -o " " in.xml
```

Comment: looks like if there is namespace prefix, the above does not seem to work.

Comment: No namespace prefix is needed here.  It's been tested with OP's XML, and it works as required.

Comment: What i meant was that if there is namespace prefix to each element in the xml, the xpath would also require the same prefix. Ofcourse, the command provided by you is working for the given xml in the original post.